# How to get a synonym from two tables?

Tags: mysql, database

I have to fetch data from a word and a synonym table with php/MySql:

```
  words              synonyms
 id|word          wordid|synonymid
 -------            -------
  1|A                  1|2    
  2|B                  2|1
  3|C                  2|3
                       3|2
```

So I want to search for word A and get back word B. Maybe INNER-JOIN is a solution?
I have already a solution, but it requires two querys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need two JOINs with the `words` table.

```
SELECT w2.word
FROM words AS w1
JOIN synonyms AS s ON s.wordid = w1.id
JOIN words AS w2 ON s.synonymid = w2.id
WHERE w1.word = 'A'
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response! The code works :))
I'm sorry, but I can't upvote your answer because I don't have 15 reputation :/

Comment: Accepting the answer is better than upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this query:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.word, GROUP_CONCAT(t3.word) AS synonyms
FROM words t1 
JOIN synonyms t2 ON t1.id = t2.wordid
JOIN words t3 ON t2.synonymid = t3.id
WHERE t1.word='B';
```

This query will return the answers in a convenient format:

```
+----+------+----------+
| id | word | synonyms |
+----+------+----------+
|  2 | B    | A,C      |
+----+------+----------+
```